# Same key with different values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Suppose python dictionary is like 
D = {'a':1,'a':2}
Can I get those 2 values with same key 
Because I want write a function so I can get dictionary like above?

Comment: You can't. Keys have to be unique.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python dict tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  By definition, dict keys are unique.

Comment: No, `dict` objects must have unique keys. In an expression like `D = {'a':1,'a':2}`, the dict is constructed taking the last key-value pair with the non-unique key, from left to right. so it will simply evaluate to `{'a':2}`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys in Python are unique. Python will resolve `D = {'a':1,'a':2}` as `D = {'a': 2}`

You can effectively store multiple values under the same key by storing a list under that key. In your case,

```
D = {'a': [1, 2]}
```

This would allow you to access the elements of 'a' by using

```
D['a'][elementIdx]   # D['a'][0] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. I set up an identical dictionary, and when attempting to print the key `'a'`, I received the secondary value, i.e., `2`. Keys are meant to be unique.

You could try something like:

```
x = {}
for i in range(2):
    x[f"a{i}"] = i
```

Which would output key values like `a0, a1, etc.`